# Lookup directory for Saxon XSL transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I have two `xml` files and `xsl` transformation for them:
`items.xml`:

```
<items>
  <item id="1">
    <name>Item1</name>
  </item>
  <item id="2">
    <name>Item2</name>
  </item>
</items>
```

`details.xml`:

```
<details>
  <item id="1">
    <details>Item1 details</details>
  </item>
</details>
```

`merge.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/items">
    <items>
      <xsl:for-each select="item">
        <item>
          <xsl:variable name="item-id" select="@id"/>
          <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="name/text()"/>
          </name>
          <xsl:if test="document('details.xml')/details/item[@id=$item-id]">
            <details>
              <xsl:value-of select="document('details.xml')/details/item[@id=$item-id]/details/text()"/>
            </details>
          </xsl:if>
        </item>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </items>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`merge.xml` is used by absolute path, but `xml` files by relative path.
To transform them I'm using Saxon jar:
`java -jar /jars/saxon.jar -s:items.xml -xsl:/xsl/merge.xsl`
but it shows me warning and can't find `details.xml` by relative path (`document('details.xml')` in `merge.xsl`):

> Warning at char 9 in xsl:if/@test on line 13 column 77 of merge.xsl:
>     FODC0002: I/O error reported by XML parser processing
>     file:/xsl/details.xml:
>     /xsl/details.xml (No such file or directory)

If I put `merge.xsl` in same directory it's working fine and merge both `xml` files as expected, but it's not possible to do it manually every time.

Is it possible to configure Saxon transformer to lookup `xml` files from `document('file.xml')` in same directory as these documents located, not in `xsl` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `document` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#document has a second parameter to provide/infer a base URI for resolving the first argument so you want `document('details.xml', .)` or `document('details.xml', /)` to use a node from the main input document as the one to infer the base URI from and not the stylesheet document.